# Vertical space in odd-dimentional sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, vector-fields, projective-space

We identify canonically $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ with $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ which we equip with the standard hermitian product.

For each $z\in\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$, we define $X_z:=iz$. It's easy to check using the hermitian product that $X$ defines a vector field on $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$.

We recall that the complex projective space is $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n:=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}^*$ and let $p:\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ the application that maps each $z\in\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$ to its class in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$.

I want to demonstrate that for all $z\in\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$, $dp_z(X_z)=0$. I tried to work in local coordinates using the standard atlases of $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$ and $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, but the computations got too messy very quickly and I wonder if there is any easy way to demonstrate it.

Comment: Have you considered the fiber of $p$ containing $z$? What is it and what is its tangent space at $z$?

Comment: @TedShifrin $p^{-1}(p(z))=S^1z$, so it is a one-dimentional manifold that can be described by the immersion $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1z,\lambda\mapsto\lambda z$. Using $ker(dp_z)=T_z(S^1z)=Im(df_1)$, we can see clearly that $X_z=df_1(i)$, so $X_z\in ker(dp_z)$.

Comment: There you go. It sounds like you should post your solution as an answer to your question!